# link_to works local, but doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, link-to, turbolinks

I have a portfolio application built with Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 5.0.0 that has links to external urls that work locally but do not work when deployed to Heroku.

```
<%= link_to image_tag(project.index_image), project.url %>
```

There are two different types of links that are not working and producing different symptoms.

**External Application Links** 
In production the links to my other applications successfully redirect to the desired urls but the url's do not update in the browser to the new page.

**Github links** 
The links to github do not work and redirect to a blank screen.  That screen displays the following error in the developer console:

```
Refused to display 'https://github.com/my_repo' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".
```

Comment: read this one carefully. i don't know if you have a chance to modify proxy server configuration on heroku, but at least you'll learn one new thing -)) https://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Just read the documentation and I have not tried modifying the content security policy.  Was wondering if you have a gem recommendation or if I'm better off modifying through Heroku?

Comment: search for `rack-cors`, i've used it a few years ago, do not know if it is still maintained, and if there is a compatible version for rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try to creating a helper class for custom URL like below

On the `helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
def custom_link(image, url)
    link_to image_tag(image), "#{url}"
end
```

And the view look like this

```
<%= custom_link project.index_image, project.url %>
```

This should work I hope because it's working my own.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.

Just tried creating a helper class as described.  Got it working locally, pushed to heroku and am still having github links fail and project links render the screen correctly but not update the url address.

Just noticed some static, hardcoded <a> tags that are performing the same way as the github tags, where the target page isn't rendering.

Comment: Would you please put the URL here, need to see URL format after mouse on the link

Comment: The url is [link](http://ryanhamill.com/).  Also noticing now that when I right click and open in a new tab, the links redirect and work properly.  It's only a regular click does not work.  

I've been using Chrome primarily but am seeing the same symptoms on Firefox. Firefox returned this error from a github.com link:

`Blocked by Content Security Policy

This page has a content security policy that prevents it from being loaded in this way.

Firefox prevented this page from loading in this way because the page has a content security policy that disallows it.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<%= link_to project.url do %>
  image_tag(project.index_image)
<% end %>
```